# Tabs opening automatically on chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have a MacBook air
On clicking on the search bar or any link, another tab is opened with some ad on it.

I tried to download things like adwcleaner etc., but I can find them only in .exe extension.

Comment: This is really 2 questions and the second one is because they are Windows apps you need a different one in OS X - keep to just the first sentence and get an answer for that then if needed ask more

Comment: This could be a problem with Chrome or a wider system problem. Could you download and run [EtreCheck](http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck), post the results in a [gist](https://gist.github.com) and add a link to the gist to your question please? That will help us give a better answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the EtreCheck and it showed that I had some adware. I downloaded AdwareMedic which removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out The Safe Mac's website (http://www.thesafemac.com/arg-identification/) on how to remove adware from OS X and Safari. It sounds like you've got Conduit or some similar adware/malware that has attached itself to Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.